# Is there a way to uninstall package in both project library and cache?

Tags: r, renv

Suppose I create a new project with renv activated.
Then I install a package by `install.packages('tictoc')`

After a while, I don't need it any more, so I remove it from my project library by `renv::remove('tictoc')`

It indeed disappeared in the folder `renv::paths$library()`. However it is still in the cached library(which by definition shared by all projects managed by renv) in `renv::paths$cache()`.

So if I want to also remove it from the cache,is there a command to do so? Or I could only remove it manually?

For just one package, that was fine, but if the package was installed with 10+ dependencies and I want to remove them from project library and meanwhile remove them from cache, what should I do?

*And if the cache's package is pointed by more than one project's library, then I shouldn't remove the package in cache; since even project A won't need it but project B may need it. If there is a method to do this, I want it to alerm me that.*

Comment: You can remove it manually, but why do you want to do this? [The whole point of a cache](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cache#Etymology_1) is that you generally don’t care about it, and ignore its existence. It is an implementation detail which magically makes ‘renv’ run faster. You don’t need to fiddle with it.

Comment: Sometimes we try some packages and afterwards not using them, the package and its dependencies will be like 10+, also some package that is out of date or has some critical bugs then no need to leave them there. And in docker or some virtual machine the resources are limited, should not put some unused package there. Those are my reason, but in normal case that is fine. @Konrad Rudolph

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer

We can use `renv::purge()` to remove package from cache.

I don't think it will warn you if there is some project library's package linked to it. So need to be very careful.